# iBooks Author iframe

Tags: html, iframe, ibooks

I want to know if i can add a **customized html page** in ibooks author via **iframe**, 
and then update that page from a server.

Purpose is to have a customize webpage with multiple links and images, and then change the contents time to time as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Widget bundle. You would basically have a widget that contains your iframe and calls your web URL, and then embed that widget into your book file. The widget is exempt from the security restriction you would encounter if putting the iframe directly in your book content. See [guidelines on using widgets in ibooks here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5068)